# Merge Pandas dataframes to create a list for duplicate matches

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['ida', 1], ['idb', 2], ['idc', 3]], columns=['A','B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['idb', 20], ['ida', 10], ['idb', 21], ['idb', 22]], columns=['A', 'C'])
```

and I would like to append the data from `df2`to `df1`*into a list*:

```
df3 = 
  |A   B  C
---------------
0 |ida 1  [10]
1 |idb 2  [20, 21, 22]
2 |idc 3  NaN
```

I can merge both frames:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left')
     A  B     C
0  ida  1  10.0
1  idb  2  20.0
2  idb  2  21.0
3  idb  2  22.0
4  idc  3   NaN
```

But then how do I "merge" matching rows? Also, in reality df2 is a lot larger and I only want to copy the columns "C", not columns "D", "E", "F"...

Alternatively, I can create a new column in df1 and then iterate over df2 to fill it:

```
for n, row in df2.iterrows():
    idx = df1.index[row['A'] == df1['A']]
    for i in idx:  # hopefully only 1 or 0 values in idx
        <assign value> df1.at[i, 'A'] = ???
```

The reason I want to have lists is that there is a flexible number of 'C'-values and I later want to calculate the average, standard deviation, ...

Edit: Typo

Comment: If want `I later want to calculate the average, standard deviation,` need scalars, working with lists is not well supoorted in pandas

Comment: So need working only with ouput from `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 0.24.x upwards of pandas you can use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df3 = (df1.merge(
            df2.groupby('A')['C'].apply(np.array),
            how='left',
            left_on='A',
            right_index=True))
```

And for your summary statistics:

```
df3['C'].apply(lambda x: np.std(x))
df3['C'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
```

Comment: `df2.groupby()` gives back a series which cannot be merged with a dataframe. If you add `pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby(...))` it works. Thanks a lot! This was fast!

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Works with version 0.24.0 for me

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 0.23.4

Comment: Yes, in version 0.24.x onwards, it's possible to merge Series with DataFrame, so long as the Series is named. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of `merging` and after that `groupby` with applying the `list` function like the following:

```
# Merge on key columns A
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A', how='outer')

# Output1
    A   B   C
0   ida 1   10.0
1   idb 2   20.0
2   idb 2   21.0
3   idb 2   22.0
4   idc 3   NaN

# Groupby and apply list to keep values
df_final = df3.groupby('A').C.apply(list).reset_index()


    A   C
0   ida [10.0]
1   idb [20.0, 21.0, 22.0]
2   idc [nan]
```

EDIT:

If you want to only bring certain columns after a merge you can do the following:
`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['A', 'C']], on='A', how='outer')`

Comment: This answer works well, too. I just accepted the other one as answer because I have to choose ONE.